# Bundler::GemfileNotFound while trying to install cms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

There is an error when I'm trying to install a CMS. It says `Bundler::GemfileNotFound`

Besides, when I run `bundle` it also says `Bundler::GemfileNotFound`

How do I fix this?

Comment: you need to add context to this. Your question is too vague. Do you even have a Gemfile ?

Answer (score 12):

I think you're getting this error *because* you didn't go into the directory.

i.e., rails new project_example

then you do

cd project_example (cd stands for change directory)

this moves you inside the project ...

then you run that command

Comment: run "bundle init" so that it creates blank Gemfile and you can edit it for your needs

Comment: That comment solved this same issue for me. I wouldn't say the answer is not constructive tbh.